# Equating symbolic coefficients

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, ode, coefficients

I would like to seek `y` particular of ODE `y'' - y' - 2y = 4x^2`

I made the following script:

```
syms x A0 A1 A2
ypa = A2*x^2+A1*x+A0; % y_p assume
cyp = diff(ypa,2) - diff(ypa) - 2*ypa % according to ODE
P1 = 4*x^2; P2 = cyp ; % Equating P1 and P2
C = coeffs(P1 - P2,x);
A0 = solve(C(1),A0) 
A1 = solve(C(2),A1) 
A2 = solve(C(3),A2)
```

I got the correct answer for `A2 = -2`. But I did not get for `A0` (should be `-3`) and `A1` (should be `2`). How to get them automatically?

P.S I'm using MATLAB R2013a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling [solve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) 3 times, once on each equation of `C`, you should call it once on the entire system of equations so that the proper substitutions are done to give you a numeric result for each variable:

```
>> [A0, A1, A2] = solve(C)

A0 =
-3

A1 =
2

A2 =
-2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gnovice. It works perfectly. Thanks also to Sardar Usama who explains me how to solve this problem instensively. Since I use the old version of Matlab, It does not work.